# Path,Roads are black in Google Maps Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, mobile

when I zoom 14 and more lines look black. When less 14, It is okay.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vDhP.jpg)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgpIk.jpg)

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GoogleMap(
      onMapCreated: (controller) {
        _googleMapController = controller;
        // rootBundle.loadString('assets/map_style.txt').then((value) {
        //   mapStyle = value;
        //   _googleMapController.setMapStyle(mapStyle);
        // }).catchError((e) {
        //   log(e.toString());
        // });
      },
      zoomControlsEnabled: false,
      liteModeEnabled: false,
      minMaxZoomPreference: const MinMaxZoomPreference(1, 20),
      mapToolbarEnabled: false,
      trafficEnabled: false,
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: widget.userLocation,
        zoom: 13,
      ),
      
      markers: {
        Marker(
          markerId: const MarkerId('userLocation'),
          position: widget.userLocation,
          icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
            BitmapDescriptor.hueRed,
          ),
          
        ),
      },
    );
  }
```

I tried to set map style and change some properties but didn't work.

Comment: This seems to be already fixed on the new map renderer as per this bug in the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/295677329

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faced same problem, try run it on real device. I have this bug only on emulator, real device works fine.