# React Native Maps - Streets turn black on Android

Tags: android, react-native, google-maps, react-native-maps

I have a React Native Application with React Native Maps, on iOS everything is working great, but in the Android Version of the app, for some reason the streets are black:
[Black Streets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu3qW.png)

I thought it was because of the custom map style, even though it clearly specified that they should be white for local (and all other roads):

```
{
    featureType: 'road.local',
    elementType: 'geometry.fill',
    stylers: [
      {
        color: '#ffffff',
      },
    ],
  },
```

but even when custom map styles are turned off the streets are always black:

```
 <MapView
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        region={{
          latitude: 49.026521,
          longitude: 20.5894,
          latitudeDelta: 0.0032,
          longitudeDelta: 0.0032,
        }}
        style={styles.mapStyle}
        zoomEnabled={true}
        scrollEnabled={true}
        showsUserLocation={true}
        // customMapStyle={CONSTANTS.MAP_STYLE}
>
```

and styles:

```
 mapStyle: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    borderRadius: 15,
  },
```

it's running in android emulator, pixel 3a API version 33, as far as I can tell the dark mode is turned off.

Comment: Having the same issue on android. Did you find a solution?

Comment: This looks like a similar issue with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77641340/path-roads-are-black-in-google-maps-flutter and this looks like it already had a fix using the [New Map Renderer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/renderer). Public Issue Tracker Link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/295677329